# "The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{x}' is already being tracked with UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm having a tracking issue when using the UserManager class. I want to update user data with roles.

```
var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(dest);
```

The code I wrote above gives me an error

error is

```
The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 432d2e6c-387e-4238-8ad8-2ef6dc41ba2e}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

my command class is

```
namespace SharedNote.Application.CQRS.Commands
{
    public class UpdateUserRoleCommand :  IRequest<IDataResponse<UserDto>>
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public class UpdateUserRoleCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<UpdateUserRoleCommand, IDataResponse<UserDto>>
        {
            private readonly IMapper _mapper;
            private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
           
            public UpdateUserRoleCommandHandler(IMapper mapper, UserManager<User> userManager)
            {
                _mapper = mapper;
                _userManager = userManager;
            }
            public async Task<IDataResponse<UserDto>> Handle(UpdateUserRoleCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var user = _userManager.Users.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == request.Id);
                if (user == null) return new ErrorDataResponse<UserDto>(null, "", 404);

                var dest = _mapper.Map<User>(request);
                dest.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(dest);

                if (!result.Succeeded) return new ErrorDataResponse<UserDto>(null, "", 400);
                var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                if (roles[0] != request.Role)
                {
                    await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, request.Role);
                }
                return new SuccessDataResponse<UserDto>(null, "", 200);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, you shouldn create a new instance and try to update existing. You have to update existing user using Mapper or manually

```
Mapper.Map<UpdateUserRoleCommand,User>(dest, user);
var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

Comment: Mapper.Map<UpdateUserRoleCommand,User>(dest, user);  ı added same code after                 dest.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;  but it gives error

Comment: @notcontrol  I don't know how your mapper is configured, I never use mappers. Maybe it is better to do it manually,  but you should update user object that you get from context, not dest that was created.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the user to your context and it will work

```
_context.Attach(user);
var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```